# select Table td range index between index

Tags: jquery, html

```
<table >
  <tr>
    <td>00 </td> <td>01 </td> <td>02 </td> <td>03 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>00 </td> <td>01 </td> <td>02 </td> <td>03 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I use jquery select TD index range 2~4 each rows.

```
$('table td').css('color' ,'red');
```

Each rows td between 02~04 .

Comment: Just to confirm, `index` or `value`?

Comment: @Satpal: i doubt that would matter. text values are based on index only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do by:

```
$(function () {
  $("table tr").each(function () {
    $(this).find("td:gt(0)").css('color' ,'red');
  });
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $("table tr").each(function () {
    $(this).find("td:gt(0)").css('color' ,'red');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>00 </td> <td>01 </td> <td>02 </td> <td>03 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>00 </td> <td>01 </td> <td>02 </td> <td>03 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

```
$(function () {        
    $("table td").filter(function () {
        var text = parseInt($(this).text(),10); 
        return  text >= 2 && text <= 4;
    }).css('background-color' ,'red');;
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("table td").filter(function() {
    var text = parseInt($(this).text(),10);
    return text >= 2 && text <= 4;
  }).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>00</td>
    <td>01</td>
    <td>02</td>
    <td>03</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>00</td>
    <td>01</td>
    <td>02</td>
    <td>03</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```